# Can I read a data file without root access

Tags: adb

I've been playing around with my phone, specifically the file `/data/system/gesture.key`, and have run into an issue.

Using adb, I can get right up to the file but I can't read it or copy it to my PC. I have two phones I'm working with - an S3 and an LG90. Neither phone is rooted and I don't really want to root them.

I keep getting `permission denied` error when trying to access the file.

Is there any way to open the file without rooting the phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply put, the chance is there. The issue is, that only the system has permission to read that file. So we need to use a system service to read the file and send it to us. AFAIK creating a backup using ADB and extracting files should be possible, but I don't know if such system files are included in a full backup using ADB. Note: Do a backup with something like `adb backup` and not via `adb shell`.

Comment: I tried the adb backup and the adb side seemed to think it worked and it told me to go verify on device. but A) the device didn't seem to know about it and B) I'm also trying to figure out how to do this without having to do anything on the device.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the file is owned by the system. No user app is able to run as the system user and thus it is not possible to copy it. The shell itself runs as a user as well, but the ADB daemon (`adbd`) seems to have system permissions needed to create backups of your system. After you have accepted/verified your PC on your phone you will not be asked again.